# Reading and writing mutliple mp3 files into one in C

Tags: c, directory, fwrite, fread

Currently, I have a program that traverses through directories and finds mp3 files. When found, I need to 1. Open the mp3 file
2. Read the mp3 file
3. Write the mp3 file to an output file.

It seems that I am reading the audio file correctly but when I write it to the output file, nothing is heard. I believe there is an issue with my fwrite arguments.

I have sectioned out the part of the code that is relevant to my question.
Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

```
void listFilesRecursively(char *basePath)
{
    char path[1000];
    int file_length;
    
    // OPEN FILE TO WRITE TO 
    FILE *output_file;
    //output_file = fopen("outputfile.txt", "w");
    if ( (output_file = fopen("output.mp3", "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR READING FILE\n");
        return ;
    }
    
    DIR *current = opendir(basePath);

    // Unable to open directory stream
    if (!current)
            return;

        while ((entry = readdir(current)) != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
             printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);

            // Construct new path from our base path
                strcpy(path, basePath);
                strcat(path, "/");
                strcat(path, entry->d_name);
            
                printf("Path: %s\n", path);
            
                file_length = strlen(entry->d_name);
                if(entry->d_name[file_length - 1] == 51 &&
                  entry->d_name[file_length - 2] == 112 &&
                  entry->d_name[file_length - 3] == 109)    
                
                {
                    
                    printf("------------------\n");
                    printf("Writing %s to file\n", entry->d_name);
                    printf("------------------\n");         

                    if(length < (num + 1))
                    {
                        length = num + 1;
                    }
                    
                    
                    FILE *mp3file;
                    if ((mp3file = fopen(path, "rb")) != NULL)
                    {
                        //SET POINTER TO THE END OF THE FILE TO GET THE SIZE
                        fseek(mp3file, 0, SEEK_END);
                        long mp3filesize = ftell(mp3file);
                        // SET POINTER BACK TO THE BEGINNING
                        fseek(mp3file, 0, SEEK_SET);
                        
                        data = realloc(data, sizeof(char*) * length);
                        data[num] = malloc(mp3filesize + 1);
                        
                        int ret = fread(data[num], 1, mp3filesize, mp3file);
                        if(ret == 0)
                        {
                            printf("nothing read\n");
                        }
                        fwrite(data[num], 1, mp3filesize, output_file);
                        fclose(mp3file);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("ERROR READING FILE\n");
                    }
                    
                    // THEN USE FSEEK 
                    
                    //strcpy(data[num], entry->d_name);
           
                    num++;
                }
                listFilesRecursively(path);
            }
        }

    closedir(current);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please provide basic troubleshooting and debugging info. Basic investigations that you should have done already. Are the file sizes the same? Are the file contents the same? If different, where do the differences start and how different is it?

Comment: If you still need further help please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Complete - provide all code necessary to build and run. Minimal - remove code not directly related to the problem. For example, if it is the write that is the problem then remove all the directory traversal, hard code the input file and show just the read/write code. Producing a minimal example is not just for posting on SO but is a standard way of debugging code.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can just concatenate mp3 files and play them as one file.

Comment: MP3 files consist of several different sections of information. You cannot simply concatenate them without handling these sections. You might want to use a library, but recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow.